# How to typecast varchar2 to float in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, casting

```
ntwt          FLOAT;

ntwt:=TO_FLOAT(substr(text,27,7));


Error(38,9): PLS-00201: identifier 'TO_FLOAT' must be declared
```

Please help

Comment: It's not at all clear what the question is.

Answer (score 4):

Although there is a FLOAT type in Oracle, it's really just there for decoration purposes as there's no difference between FLOAT and NUMBER. In SYS.STANDARD FLOAT is defined as

```
subtype FLOAT is NUMBER;
```

Therefore, just use the `TO_NUMBER` function to do your conversion, as in:

```
ntwt := TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(TEXT, 27, 7));
```

Either that or define your own TO_FLOAT function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TO_FLOAT(s IN VARCHAR2) AS FLOAT IS
BEGIN
  RETURN TO_NUMBER(s);
END TO_FLOAT;
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score -1):

There is not a TO_FLOAT function in ORACLE, you can use:

```
TO_BINARY_FLOAT(substr(text,27,7))
```