# How to remove single inverted comma from stored proc

Tags: python, pandas, oracle, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

I am stuck at the last movement, i need to remove single inverted commas from price variable that i am parsing in a stored proc

```
            Body_content = message.Body
            Body_content = Body_content[:Body_content.find("Regards")].strip()
            df = pd.DataFrame([Body_content])
            print(df.to_string())
            Ticker = df.to_string()[-82:-74]
            print(Ticker)
            price = df.to_string()[-8:]
            print(price)
            Date = df.to_string()[-21:-11]
            print(Date)
            Pkey = 116010910
            #print(EMAIL_CONTNT)

con = engine.connect()

date = datetime.datetime.strptime(Date,"%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%d%b%Y")
#print(date)
#tp = "call CORE_VALUATIONS.VALUATIONS.INSERTEQCLOSINGPRICE({,to_date(({Ticker}),'ddmonyyyy'),{price},NULL,NULL);"
con.execute('call CORE_VALUATIONS.VALUATIONS.INSERTEQCLOSINGPRICE(int(%s), %s,float(%s),NULL,NULL)',(Pkey,date,price))
```

[image]

Comment: can anyone pls help

Comment: maybe it is not preferred but you can always put value directly to string using `f-string` or other method to format string.

Comment: Do not put the value in the stored procedure with an `f-string`, this is how you get SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

I am not well acquainted with Oracle SQL, but looking through the [data conversion documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Data-Type-Comparison-Rules.html) and this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24028782/17676984), the way to convert a string to a int or a float seems to either implicitly or via a `TO_*` function like [`TO_NUMBER`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/TO_NUMBER.html).

Comment: thanks Ijmc, i am still exploring, will keep you posted

Answer (score 0):

it got resolved using the following insert(%d, %s, %f, NULL, NULL)' % (int(Pkey), date, float(price))

Comment: Good to hear that you got it resolved. FYI, `float(price)` is a bit of a red flag. Using FLOAT for monetary values (like prices) is widely considered a bad practice because floating-point numbers are, by nature, imprecise. It is better to use DECIMAL. (DECIMAL(18, 4) is a common choice.)

Comment: thanks Gord, i will surely try decimal inplace of float so it should be like decimal(price) ?

Comment: If `price` is a string then `from decimal import Decimal` allows us to use `Decimal(price)` on the Python side. Note that the database columns should be DECIMAL (not FLOAT) as well.

Comment: This still leaves you open to SQL injection attacks, and isn't the best regarding performance & scalability.  Please use bind variables as described in the user documentation: https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html Also use `callproc()` to call stored procedures: https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/plsql_execution.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `callproc()` and use bind variables, see https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/plsql_execution.html

You *must* use bind variables to help protect against SQL injection attacks.  They will also help performance and scalability.  Try something like this, which internal does binding:

```
cursor.callproc('CORE_VALUATIONS.VALUATIONS.INSERTEQCLOSINGPRICE', 
                [Pkey,date,price])
```

Also consider upgrading to the latest version of the Python driver - it got renamed from cx_Oracle to python-oracledb, see the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a)

Comment: Thanks christopher, i am using the following IDE "from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine" , do i still need to upgrade ?